# Proper settings of the brush in weight pane mode

Tags: weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

I am trying to paint some parts with zero weight with "draw" mode in blue colour.
The problem is that the brush does not catch some parts of the mesh, and they move.
In the example - I try to rotate the right hand, and some parts of the hat (on the head) also are moving - I cant paint them in blue.
What settings shall I do for the brush, so that to be able to paint these parts in blue (zero weight)? I have already tried a couple of settings of the brush - sphere, projected and others - but without results.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove bone influence, it's far easier to select the verts and remove from the vertex group:

[image]

If I click that Remove button, it will remove all influence from "body" for all vertices that I have selected.

In terms of the explicit question, you want settings like this to have super-duper subtract effectiveness:

[image]

Advanced/Front faces disabled lets it paint through the mesh.  Constant falloff curve prevents it from affecting less at the edge of the brush.  Disabling falloff/front-face falloff prevents it from painting less when painting at an angle to the mesh.  Project falloff shape makes it paint a cone/cylinder from the camera to the brush and past, instead of a sphere on the nearest surface to the brush.

Comment: I understand what's the Falloff shape means at last. I wonder why when you paint with a Strength of 0, the vertices are not removed from the group and they will still be displayed as blue, instead of considering a Strength of 0 as a Remove action

Comment: Nathan, many thanks for the detailed answer. Now with these settings of the brush, it is much better than before. Still is difficult sometimes to paint some parts of the mesh ( or remove weights), the brush does not catch them the first time, and there is a result if I rotate the object, to paint it from another angle.